# Is npm version 5 and above compatible with react native?

Tags: react-native, npm

I am recently installing npm and react native 
I heard from a 2years old tutorial that new npm versions don't support react native
has this issue been fixed or is npm@5 still incompatible with react native?

Answer (score 0):

Try latest node modules and react-native package.It is better to use Node Version 10 or above for better development environment.